# SAPUI5 vizframe dual_stacked_chat show 2 different y axis

Tags: charts, sapui5

I made a dual_stacked_column chart.
Unfortunately the chart shows 2 different y axis. What do I have to set so that the y-axis get the same value? (vizscale?)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I searched for a long time and found the solution. The maxValues ​​are just an example, but the glossy effect is cool.

HTML:

```html
vizProperties="{  plotArea : { drawingEffect : 'glossy',  
                  primaryScale : { fixedRange : true,  minValue : 0,  maxValue : 6000 },                        
                  secondaryScale : {  fixedRange : true,  minValue : 0,  maxValue : 6000 } } }"
```

JS:

```js
// set the scales 
var oVizFrame = this.oVizFrame = this.getView().byId("idVizFrame1"); 
// get manual input 
var oYAxis = this.getView().byId("idYAxis"); 
var sYAxisValue = oYAxis.getValue(); 

oVizFrame.setVizProperties({ 
    plotArea: { 
        primaryScale: {fixedRange : true, minValue: 0, maxValue: sYAxisValue }, 
        secondaryScale: {fixedRange : true, minValue: 0, maxValue: sYAxisValue }                    
    }    
});
```

Comment: Nice you saved me hours of reasearch. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem wir a dual bar chart.
I dont know if you can apply the same logic but its worth a try.

Change the chart type to stacked column and give the measure deklaration both columns.
example:

```
<viz.feeds:FeedItem id='valueAxisFeed' uid="valueAxis" type="Measure" values="values1,values2" />
```

now they should render on the same scale.

Hope it helps!